# Manage content items using Views

Tags: 7, views, media

I'm creating a user-upload photo gallery, and I require admin approval on all user uploads. Photos will be a content type with just a few fields (Image, Taxonomy, Tags). I'd like to be able to view a grid of all uploaded photos at a glance, and then check a box next to each one and publish/unpublish all that are selected. Is there a method by which I an do this using Views? If not, is there another method/module that can provide this type of functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a content view, filter by your gallery content type, add the image field, add the field  "Content: Published" (to let you know if content is published). Then add  "Bulk operations: Content" (you need to install [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module). In the field settings you should select the option "Publish content" and "Unpublish content". You should now be able to bulk publish and unpublish the image galleries.